# eclipse - package org.testng does not exist

Tags: java, selenium, testng

> ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[19,18]
>   package org.testng does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[20,18]
>   package org.testng does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[21,30]
>   package org.testng.annotations does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[22,30]
>   package org.testng.annotations does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[23,30]
>   package org.testng.annotations does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[24,30]
>   package org.testng.annotations does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[25,39]
>   package com.relevantcodes.extentreports does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[26,39]
>   package com.relevantcodes.extentreports does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[27,39]
>   package com.relevantcodes.extentreports does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[35,9]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ExtentReports   location: class
>   webAutoTest.CitrussTV.UAEArabicCODClass [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[36,9]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ExtentTest   location: class
>   webAutoTest.CitrussTV.UAEArabicCODClass [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/SendEMailcitruss.java:[5,1]
>   package javax.mail does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/SendEMailcitruss.java:[6,1]
>   package javax.mail.internet does not exist [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/PoojaPatange/eclipse-workspacepractice/webAutoTest/src/main/java/webAutoTest/CitrussTV/UAEArabicCODClass.java:[317,31]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class ITestResult   location: class
>   webAutoTest.CitrussTV.UAEArabicCODClassenter image description here

Comment: its not allowingme to post images , Actually i have application its in arabic language  dnt have english code i have used arabic sentence in my java code for comparison if i m running from ecplise its giving correct result. when im trying to run from cmd its giving above compilation error

Comment: Please download testNG from eclipse market place

Comment: @AnkurSingh, but she is able to run from eclipse. Isn't that should already be there?

Comment: @PoojaPathange, Can you paste the testng dependency that you have in your POM?

Comment: yes im able to run from eclipse dnt have any issue while running from eclipse.  i have issue only running in command promt . and jenkins build also failing ,can any one plz suggest me on this - i think this issue mainly comming becz of im using arabic language in code compilation error also indicated same code line error -  if (shippingText.equals("عفواً, لا تتوافر أسعار لهذا الطلب في الوقت الحالي")) { my code  , i dnt have any other option complete app in arabic no english

Comment: @eduPeeth <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.10</version>
   <!--  <scope>compile</scope> -->
</dependency>

Comment: Can you please try uncommenting scope and see?

Comment: @eduPeeth i tried that also and im using ecplise oxygen how can i chcek which version testng im having

Comment: You have it in your POM as you pasted `<version>6.9.10</version>`. You can see `testng` in your build path?

Comment: @eduPeeth    Now im facing this issue have added jar file for mail do i need to add dependency for this also ? endEMailcitruss.java:[5,0] error: package javax.mail does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\PoojaPatange\git\MyLocalGit\webAutoTest\src\main\java\webAutoTest\SendEMailcitruss.java:[6,0] error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
[ERROR] \Users\PoojaPatange\git\MyLocalGit\webAutoTest\src\main\java\webAutoTest\SendEMailcitruss.java:[26,5] error: cannot find symbol

Comment: Dependency is to be added when you want to download the jars automatically. If you have added the jar, you may choose not to. But I will suggest add it to POM and then update and build your project. Is it there in build path?

Comment: Is your above exception resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Install TestNG in eclipse as below:

1. Eclipse --> Help --> Eclipse Marketplace
2. Search TestNG --> Search result shows "TestNG for Eclipse"
3. Install

After the installation, try to import as below:

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
```

It should work fine without any compilation errors